# yii BBII Forum editMe Editor not working

Tags: php, yii, assets

I have integrated the BBII forum in my site. In BBII forum, there is a default editor 'editme'. The editor is working correctly in local. But in online, it displays the following error message

The asset "/home/mars/web/protected/modules/bbii/extensions/editMe/vendors/CKEditor" to be published does not exist.

Comment: I have fixed the issue while changing the directory name for "ckeditor" to "CKEditor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this wiki can help to you

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bbii/
```